# Is there any way to hide bullets of <li> element which is having empty div

Tags: javascript, css

I am dynamically generating li elements.
some of li element is having empty div.
like

```
<ul class="mybuttons">
   <li class="mybutton"><div>kkk</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div>llll</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

i don't want to show 3rd li element bullet on ui, but want to show other two li bullets.
is there any way to fix this?

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Without changing the structure, adding classes, etc.?

Comment: Why are you using those divs within the list items?

Comment: Dynamically creating them where? Should be relatively easy to add a class when you create them depending on whatever parameter(s) contain the content in the div being empty or not

Comment: [CSS Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview) would allow for `li:has(> div:empty)`.

Comment: If you're creating the elements, then you can also omit `li`s with empty `div`s. Then you dont have to worry about hiding the bullets.

Comment: @Xufox - But what if it has *other* children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said you're creating the elements. If so, then just leave off that `li` or apply a class to it when the `div` is empty that sets `list-style: none`.

**If** you're doing this after the fact, then without changing the structure, adding classes, etc., I can't think of a CSS solution that works based on the div being empty (rather than it always being the third item, which I'm sure isn't the question).

The JavaScript solution is simple, but I don't like using JavaScript for this.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".mybuttons li");
for (const item of items) {
  if (!item.textContent.trim()) {
    item.style.listStyle = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="mybuttons">
   <li class="mybutton"><div>kkk</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div>llll</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

Or with ES5 only:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".mybuttons li");
for (var n = 0; n < items.length; ++n) {
  if (!items[n].textContent.trim()) {
    items[n].style.listStyle = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="mybuttons">
   <li class="mybutton"><div>kkk</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div>llll</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

---

I shouldn't have used `style.listStyle` above, I should have done what I said in the first paragraph above and used a class:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".mybuttons li");
for (const item of items) {
  if (!item.textContent.trim()) {
    item.classList.add("empty");
  }
}
```

```css
.empty {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mybuttons">
   <li class="mybutton"><div>kkk</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div>llll</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` to select all the `li` elements and inside a `forEach` loop if the text in a `div` is empty remove the `list style` from it.

```js
var a=document.querySelectorAll('li');
a.forEach((e)=>{
if(e.childNodes[0].textContent=="")
e.style.listStyle='none';
})
```

```html
<ul class="mybuttons" >
   <li class="mybutton"><div>kkk</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div>llll</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div></div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div>erere</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div></div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div>rere</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With JS:

```
{
 const init = () => {
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll(`.mybutton`);
  const allBtns = Array.from(btns);

  btns.forEach(btn => {
   if(btn.textContent === ''){
    btn.style.listStyle = 'none';
   }
  }
 }
 init();
}
```

This might work

Answer (score -1):

just check the text in the li element and eventually remove it:

```js
let items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  let text = items[i].innerText;
  if(!text) items[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<ul class="mybuttons">
   <li class="mybutton"><div>kkk</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div>llll</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is jquery tagged in the question?

Answer (score -4):

Yes. Use the `list-style` property and assign `none` to it.

```html
<ul class="mybuttons">
   <li class="mybutton"><div>kkk</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton"><div>llll</div></li>
   <li class="mybutton" style="list-style: none;"><div>HHH</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That does **all** of them. The question is clear about only wanting the last one handled. *(not my downvote)*